# Need a way to disable access to Chrome task manager?

Tags: google-chrome, task-manager, extension

So basically, I've installed a few extensions that block access to certain sites/keywords that all work perfectly, but unfortunately for me I found that getting past these extensions is as easy as opening Chrome task manager and hitting the kill button. Is there any way at all to disable access to the chrome task manager (this is for my PC not a business computer or anything) or tell chrome to restart said extensions as soon as they're killed?

Comment: Is there anything to prevent user from simply disabling the extension in options?

Comment: "I found that getting past these extensions is as easy as ...".  You do understand there is a second workaround you have likely not thought of, you can just remove the Chrome profile, all installed extensions would no longer be installed.